# Instead of using existing docker volume, couchdb docker image always create new volume

Tags: docker, couchdb

In my ubuntu 18.04, installed couch db using [this repo](https://hub.docker.com/_/couchdb). In order to data persistance, i have created docker volume using the command `docker volume create --name couchdbvolume`.

I used `docker run -p 5984:5984 -d couchdb -v couchdbvolume:/opt/couchdb/data --name some-couchdb` command to create new docker process. Instead of using existing volume, every time docker creates new volume. So i loss data in every restart.

As per [this question](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/2967/why-are-unnamed-volumes-created-when-docker-compose-up-is-run-and-do-these-dou) , un-named volumes are created if the docker file doesn't have name in volume keyword. I think because of [this line](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-docker/blob/c215380beab63ab562a297d3d4013e2ca34458ce/2.3.0/Dockerfile#L123) the volume doesn't have name. so it creates un-named volume.

Instead of multiple docker volume,
I expect, only one docker volume(i have only one couchdb docker image)

Comment: Weird request, but could you check if changing the order of arguments resolve the issue? put the image name at the end of the command:
`docker run -p 5984:5984 -d -v couchdbvolume:/opt/couchdb/data --name some-couchdb couchdb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/), options should precede the image name.

> $ docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]

please try the following:
`docker run -p 5984:5984 -d -v couchdbvolume:/opt/couchdb/data --name some-couchdb couchdb`